# Is steam a subtype of smoke?

Tags: word-usage

Steam is defined as pure water vapor. Smoke is water vapor, a mix of gases, and soot of some sort. So is steam a subtype of smoke?

Smoke from something that is completely burned wouldn't have soot but would still have water vapor and carbon dioxide, making it even less different than steam and it's appearance would likely be identical since the carbon dioxide couldn't be seen anyways.

Comment: Insurance companies have probably addressed this. A search through lexis nexis for legal precedents would likely give you a practical answer. I don’t have access to lexis nexis but others might.

Comment: Not in common usage (I assert, no numbers to back this up).  Smoke issues from stuff burning, steam issues from water boiling.  Sure, burning material will often produce steam as you suggest, but that's not something most of us think when we see a fire burning.  As for 'smoke' lacking particulate matter, being formed only of carbon dioxide and water vapour, most of us wouldn't recognise smoke without particulate matter as smoke - it would be invisible and odourless.  In common usage smoke is both visible and odourous.

Comment: Smoke is visible, and different from water vapour which has condensed into steam. Smoke contains soot particles.

Comment: Some people have milk and sugar in their tea. Their tea consists of water, sugar, milk  and 'tea derivatives'. Does this make milk 'a subtype of tea'? It's a constituent of some people's tea. // 'Steam' is often used more broadly for water vapour, so this must be another definition.

Comment: Are you asking about the vocabulary terms 'steam' and 'smoke', about common usage, or about scientific usage? Whatever your answer there, the two only overlap in the most superficial of ways as both are misty gaseous white floating stuff in the air. And no, neither is a hyponym of the other.

Comment: I once, aged 7, had the most terrific argument with my father about what to call the visible clouds of stuff which emerge from the chimneys of steam railway locomotives. He said it was 'steam'. I said it was a mixture of smoke and water vapour (I had just seen a Stanier 'Black 5' working hard and the exhaust was _very_ dark). I also knew that steam was invisible. I was, I guess, an annoyingly precocious little squirt (especially on my pet subject), and Dad just would not back down.

Answer (score 3):

There is, in current English a clear distinction between **smoke** and **steam**

OED

> Steam:  6. a. **The vapour into which water is converted when heated.**
>
> **In popular language**, applied to the visible vapour which floats in the air in the form of a white cloud or mist, and which consists of minute globules or vesicles of liquid water suspended in a mixture of gaseous water and air. (Also sometimes applied to the vapour arising from other liquids when heated.)
>
> **In modern scientific and technical language**, [the word "steam" is] **applied only to water in the form of an invisible gas.** The invisible ‘steam’, in the modern scientific sense, is, when its temperature is lowered, converted into the white vapour called ‘steam’ in popular language, and this under continued cooling, becomes ‘water’ in the liquid form. dry steam, in Steam-engine working, steam containing no suspended vesicles of water: opposed to wet steam.
>
> 1884   C. E. Dutton in 4th Ann. Rep. U.S. Geol. Surv. 1882–3 110   Condensed steam floating away in the form of white vapor.
>
> 1894   Times 15 Aug. 12/2   A boiler which supplies wet steam is a bad boiler, because wet steam is prejudicial to the efficiency of the engine.
>
> 1895   Model Steam Eng. 51   The purpose of the steam-dome is to collect the steam in as dry a condition as possible.

If you boil a kettle of water and observe what comes out of the spout at a pressure, the first few centimeter are invisible, this is steam. After this, the visible part - the cloud of steam - is technically not "steam" but "water vapour". Steam possesses a lot of energy - water vapour does not.

However, as you see from the definition above - these clouds of steam are usually called **steam**.

Smoke is, essentially, particulate matter:

> smoke, n. **1. a. The visible volatile product given off by burning or smouldering substances.**
>
> α.1774   O. Goldsmith Hist. Earth III. 156   A large fire..filling the whole place with smoke.
>
> 1829   E. Bulwer-Lytton Devereux I. i. viii. 76   Don Diego, inhaling the fragrant weed..replied to the request of his petitioner by smoke.
>
> 1888   F. Hume Madame Midas i. v. 39   The smoke was pouring out thick and black from the tall red chimney.

Steam is not a subtype of smoke, any more than "fumes" would be.